# TCP client not working correcty golang

Tags: go, tcp

I have rest-ful interface written in golang. I need to do the authentication on each endpoint. once authentication is done I have to forward it back to a tcp server. 
I created a tcp client and any value that is coming from the channel is to be send to tcp server. the channel is populated from the http request body.
The issue is that once I issue curl command the client is stuck with no response; so obviously I am doing something wrong not sure what is wrong. does anyone have any insights on what my problem might be?

```
 package main

            import (
                "bufio"
                "encoding/json"
                "flag"
                "fmt"
                "io/ioutil"
                "log"
                "net"
                "net/http"
                "net/http/httputil"
                "net/url"
                "os"
                "strconv"

                auth "github.com/abbot/go-http-auth"
            )

            type Configuration struct {
                Server        string
                Port          int64
                UserName      string
                Pwd           string
                Realm         string
                ProxyPort     int64
                Edeserver     string

            }

            var (
                Config *Configuration
                logp   = flag.Bool("log", false, "enable logging")
            )

            func ReadConfiguration() {
                file, _ := os.Open("Config.json")
                decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
                Config = &Configuration{}
                err := decoder.Decode(&Config)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("error:", err)
                }

            }

            func Secret(user, realm string) string {
                if user == Config.UserName {
                    // password is "hello"
                    return Config.Pwd
                }
                return ""
            }

            func reverseProxyTows(w http.ResponseWriter, authenticatedRequest *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
                req := &authenticatedRequest.Request

                if *logp {
                    log.Println(" Authenticated Username ", authenticatedRequest.Username)
                    log.Println(" Authenticated URL ", req.URL.RequestURI())
                }

                destinationURL := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d", Config.Server, Config.Port)
                u, err := url.Parse(destinationURL)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                if *logp {
                    log.Println("reverse_proxy", u)
                }

                reverseProxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)

                reverseProxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)
            }

            func openConnectionTotcp(edechannel chan string) {
                conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", Config.Edeserver)
                text := <-edechannel
                fmt.Fprintf(conn, text+"\n")
                message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
                fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
            }


            func main() {
                ReadConfiguration()
                flag.Parse()
                c := make(chan string)
                go openConnectionTotcp(c)

                fmt.Printf("Started proxy to destination server %v:%d and is listening on %d ", Config.Server, Config.Port, Config.ProxyPort)

                authenticator := auth.NewBasicAuthenticator(Config.Realm, Secret)
                http.HandleFunc("/", authenticator.Wrap(reverseProxyTows))
                http.HandleFunc("/tyrion/1", authenticator.Wrap(func(w http.ResponseWriter, authenticatedRequest *auth.AuthenticatedRequest) {
                    req := &authenticatedRequest.Request
                    bodyBytes, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
                    if err2 != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err2)
                    }
                    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
                    c <- bodyString
                    fmt.Fprintf(w, "success")
                }))
                http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.FormatInt(Config.ProxyPort, 10), nil)
            }
```

Comment: It seems like you execution flow blocked on "c <- bodyString". It may happens when there isn't exist any consumer for channel. Please, sure that that you don't have any error here " conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", Config.Edeserver)"

Comment: To start, you're not checking the errors from `net.Dial` or `ReadString`, you aren't closing the tcp connection, and if you were to try and read multiple messages, you're throwing away the `bufio.Reader`, which may have buffered data. You also only call `tcp.Dial` once then exit the goroutine, so even if it works it could only be for the very first http request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code execution blocks at `c <- bodyString` because nothing appears to be reading from that unbuffered channel. That line will pause execution until another routine reads from the channel.

Comment: nope that is not true openConnectionTotcp has a chan argument and that go routine reads from it  ```func openConnectionTotcp(edechannel chan string) {
                conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", Config.Edeserver)
                text := <-edechannel
                fmt.Fprintf(conn, text+"\n")
                message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
                fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
            }
```

Comment: That routine will consume a single message, then return, after which any writes to the channel will block forever. You also throw away the error from tcp.Dial, so who knows what's happening in that routine.

Comment: tcp dial does work as I am running  a local tcp server and I do see messages on tcp server side. the client that make curl request is hanging. how `That routine will consume a single message, then return,` would it return as I am not closing the channel in the first place

Comment: It doesn't matter if you close the channel or not, the function returns. Knowing your TCP listener gets a call doesn't tell you that Dial was successful. Unproven assumptions lead to defects!